# sparse norm for optimization problem

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, convex-optimization

I want to solve an optimization problem in general form:

$$\arg \min f(x) + \lambda *g(x)$$

and i want to choose / define a $g(x)$ in a way to have a sparse solution such that between two possible answers $A=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}0.5\\0.5\\0\end{bmatrix}$, it chooses A.

And of course $\|A\|_1=\|B\|_1$ and $\|A\|_2 > \|B\|_2$.

I know that using $\|A\|_p$ with $p<1$ could be a good criteria, but it is NP-hard problem and makes the optimization problem more difficult.

I also noticed $sign(A)$ is another good guess, but then it is not diffrentiable in from the optimization point of view!

Comment: Does $norm$ have to be a proper norm or must it only reflects the sparseness of your candidate $x$ ?

Comment: If you want to have a solution strategy which is guaranteed to find the optimal solution in polynomial time, you will not be able to do better than using the 1-norm.

Comment: Indeed, $norm_p(A)$ is a misnomer for $p<1$. Such a function is a true norm only for $p\geq 1$. It is my personal crusade to get people to stop using "norm" improperly in such contexts :-)

Comment: sign doesn't make sense. With that choice, $(1,-1,0)$ would give the same cost as $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: Good point! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As someone suggested earlier that for getting sparse solution in polytime, you should use $\|\cdot\|_1$ norm. Very general and fast methods to solve minimization problem of type $f(x)+\lambda g(x)$ are known as proximal algorithms (check wiki or [paper](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5610-stochastic-proximal-gradient-descent-with-acceleration-techniques.pdf)). Here, $f(\cdot)$ is data fitting term which is convex and differentiable whereas $g(\cdot)$ is any regularizer (which in your case is 1-norm).

Comment: As i mentioned in my question via giving an example, $\|\cdot\|_1$ norm doesn't solve my problem. I already tried that!

Comment: Then you re out of luck if you want to do it provably fast and optimal. However, if you simply want to get a solution, and accept that it might fail on some problems, nothing stops you from  using $|x|^p$ for your favorite $p<1$. Nothing special about that in terms of implementing a local nonlinear solver. Starting at the solution obtained from the $||\cdot||_1$-norm is a reasonable approach.

Comment: yes. $\|x\|_p$ is not convex for $p<1$.