# Encouraging sparse output in optimization problem

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, machine-learning, numerical-optimization, sparsity

I am trying to define an optimization problem:
$$ \min_\theta \sum_{x\in X} L(x, \theta, f_\theta(x),\delta_\theta(x)) + \lambda_s S(\delta_\theta(x)) $$
where $X$ is the dataset, $\theta$ are the parameters of the function being optimized ("learned"), $L$ is a loss function, and $S$ is some kind of differentiable sparsity-encouraging penalty, which is what I am trying to determine.

Essentially, my network has two outputs: $f_\theta(x)$ and $\delta_\theta(x)\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and I know that $\delta_\theta(x)$ should be quite sparse. It's sparsity level will depend on $x$. My question is how to encourage this in the cost function (within a machine learning context).

A common sparsifying penalty is the $L_1$ norm (a relaxation of the $L_0$ norm), which is fine, but I *don't* really want to shrink or restrict the non-zero elements. (Related: [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454777/sparse-norm-for-optimization-problem), [[2]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1904767/why-small-l1-norm-means-sparsity), [[3]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2382203/understanding-weighted-l-1-norm)). The loss $L$ is already very complicated (non-convex, but differentiable), so my feeling is that the convexity of $L_1$ is not terribly important.

Another penalty (e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862775/convex-optimization-with-ell-0-norm)) is to use 
$$ S(\delta) = \sum_i \log(1 + |\delta_i|/\xi) $$
and the smoothed $L_0$ penalty:
$$ S(\delta) = -\sum_i \exp(-\delta_i/\sigma) $$
for some small $\sigma$ (which can be iteratively tuned).

**Questions**:

- Besides needing to tune $\sigma$, is there any reason to use $L_1$ versus the two $S(\delta)$ functions above?
- Why don't I see the $L_p$ "norms" with $p<1$ (at least not that I've seen)? E.g. $S_{1/2}(\delta) = \sum_i \sqrt{\delta_i}$?

Comment: you lose convexity for $p<1$

Comment: @LinAlg This is true, but I felt perhaps it may not have been as important, since $L$ is a loss function of the deep networks $\delta_\theta$ and $f_\theta$, which is itself already not convex.